# Why is my REQ.body.imageURL undefined in PUT method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to write the back-end for a foodie review app. The problem I'm having is at the `PUT` method, when I'm trying to modify a certain post, the `req.body` does not contain the `imageUrl` if I do not modify the URL . When `req.file` exists (the image), then everything works, because I set up a new imageURL. For some reasons I get the `userId`, `description` and everything else back except the `imageUrl`.

Here is my code:

```
exports.modifySauce = (req, res, next) => {
  let sauce = new Sauce({ _id: req.params._id });
  if (req.file) {
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
    req.body.sauce = JSON.parse(req.body.sauce);
    sauce = {
      _id: req.params.id,
      name: req.body.sauce.name,
      manufacturer:req.body.sauce.manufacturer,
      mainPepper:req.body.sauce.mainPepper,
      description: req.body.sauce.description,
      imageUrl: url + '/images/' + req.file.filename,
      heat: req.body.sauce.heat,
      userId: req.body.sauce.userId
    };
  } else {
    sauce = {
      _id: req.params.id,
      name: req.body.name,
      manufacturer:req.body.manufacturer,
      mainPepper:req.body.mainPepper,
      description: req.body.description,
      imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
      heat: req.body.heat,
      userId: req.body.userId
    };
  }
  Sauce.updateOne({_id: req.params.id}, sauce).then(
    () => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Sauce updated successfully!'
      });
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
};
```

More information, in my [Repo.](https://github.com/vladnec/Foodie-Review-App)

And here is the front end repo. 
https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/nem-stack-hot-takes

Comment: It seems you're not passing an **imageUrl** parameter along with your PUT request. When **req.file** is specified, you're getting imageUrl from **req.file.filename**, but in the problematic case when **req.file** is not specified, you're getting imageUrl from **req.body.imageUrl**. Double check your front-end code or Postman and make sure you're specifying an **imageUrl** parameter in your PUT request. Better yet, add it to your question.

Comment: try this , open your frontend , open inpect element by pressing f12 and go on networks. update your url and select most recent url from network which will your put url.
Now check if imageUrl is present there. Ensure that character cases are same as well